# Math.random reproducing value twice

Tags: javascript

Having a bit of problem with something surely most of you will find trivial, but still would appreciate your help. It's our favorite Rock Papaer Scissors game:

```js
var user = document.querySelector(".userchoice");
var computer = document.querySelector(".computerchoice");
var startBtn = document.querySelector(".startBtn");
var result = document.querySelector(".result");

var winStates = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

startBtn.addEventListener("click", playGame);

function playGame() {
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  user.classList.add("count-in");
  computer.classList.add("count-in");
}

document.addEventListener("animationend", function () {
  user.classList.remove("count-in");
  computer.classList.remove("count-in");
  startBtn.disabled = false;
  var randomU = winStates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  var randomC = winStates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  computer.className = "computerchoice " + randomC;
  user.className = "userchoice " + randomU;
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.player {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 100px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.player p {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.player div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Rock {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Rock);
}

.Paper {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Paper);
}

.Scissors {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Scissors);
}

.Rock,
.Paper,
.Scissors {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.startBtn {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

@keyframes count-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.count-in {
  animation: 0.7s count-in 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>

  <div class="player">
    <div class="userchoice Rock"></div>
    <p>Player 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="player">
    <div class="computerchoice Rock"></div>
    <p>Computer</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result"></div>

  <button class="startBtn">Play</button>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

The problem gets when Math.random is executed, it seems like it is being triggered two times and getting two values out of the winStates array. Naturaly it should pick one value and concat it with the css class already defined

Comment: _"...and getting two values out of the winStates array"_ - like `randomU` and `randomC`? o.O

Comment: You haven't shown your CSS code, but would it be possible that there are two animations ending at the same time?

Comment: This looks like it's working to me? I only see one result from each Player.

Comment: You only _see_ one result but the code will run twice.

Answer (score 0):

The `count-in` class is added to two elements so the `animationend` event listener will fire twice.

Since the animations run concurrently, and therefore end at the same moment, you should be able to get away with binding the event to a single element, `userchoice` or `computerchoice` by using...

```
document.querySelector('.userchoice').addEventListener("animationend", ...
```

```js
var user = document.querySelector(".userchoice");
var computer = document.querySelector(".computerchoice");
var startBtn = document.querySelector(".startBtn");
var result = document.querySelector(".result");

var winStates = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

startBtn.addEventListener("click", playGame);

function playGame() {
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  user.classList.add("count-in");
  computer.classList.add("count-in");
}

document.querySelector('.userchoice').addEventListener("animationend", function () {

  console.log('animationend event');

  user.classList.remove("count-in");
  computer.classList.remove("count-in");
  startBtn.disabled = false;
  var randomU = winStates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  var randomC = winStates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  computer.className = "computerchoice " + randomC;
  user.className = "userchoice " + randomU;
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.player {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 100px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.player p {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.player div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.Rock {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Rock);
}

.Paper {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Paper);
}

.Scissors {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100?text=Scissors);
}

.Rock,
.Paper,
.Scissors {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.startBtn {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 100px;
}

@keyframes count-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.count-in {
  animation: 0.7s count-in 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>

  <div class="player">
    <div class="userchoice Rock"></div>
    <p>Player 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="player">
    <div class="computerchoice Rock"></div>
    <p>Computer</p>
  </div>

  <div class="result"></div>

  <button class="startBtn">Play</button>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```